# how to use class variable in method in class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I try to use x in method , error is resulted saying " 'x' is not defined"

```
class main:
    x=20
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func(self):
        z=x+10
        print(z)

obj1=main()
obj1.func()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use it through `self`:

```
class main:
    x=20
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func(self):
        z=self.x+10
        print(z)

obj1=main()
obj1.func()
```

or through `self.__class__`

```
class main:
    x=20
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func(self):
        z=self.__class__.x+10
        print(z)

obj1=main()
obj1.func()
```

or through class name:

```
class main:
    x=20
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func(self):
        z=main.x+10
        print(z)

obj1=main()
obj1.func()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class main:
    x=20
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func(self):
        z=self.x+10
        print(z)

obj1=main()
obj1.func()
```

I always perfer the code goes as the following, to init the value in constructor method.

```
class main:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 20

    def func(self):
        z=self.x+10
        print(z)

obj1=main()
obj1.func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line of func to

```
  z = self.x + 10
```